# Keyboard not disappearing when iScroll used

Tags: android, keyboard, iscroll4

We are using iscroll4 for an android app. If iScroll is not used, when I touch on input field, the  keyboard opening automatically and it disappear when I touch anywhere outside of input field. If iScroll is used the same is not happening. When I touch outside of iScroll enabled div keyboard closed automatically. How can avoid this problem? I would like to keyboard act normally when iScroll is used.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `scroll` is being triggered rather than `focus`, and you just need to prevent that from happening with form elements.

```
myScroll = new iScroll('scroller-parent', {
    // All our params are set

    // Allow form elements to be clickable/selected
    onBeforeScrollStart: function (e) {
        var target = e.target;
        while (target.nodeType != 1) target = target.parentNode;

        if (target.tagName != 'SELECT' && target.tagName != 'INPUT' && target.tagName != 'TEXTAREA')
            e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```